# Help parsing string with random delimiters

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am new to programming in general. I'm writing a program that takes a command line argument and a input string once started. It can convert to pig latin, undo the pig latin, or do rot13.

I have all of my functions working flawlessly but I need help parsing the input string as all the functions can only do one word at a time and it can only contain letters. Any word with a delimiter in it has to be treated as two words, such as no0b would be treated as no-0-b with the zero not going into the function.

My understanding of how this would work would be to have a output string and add the words to it as they are done then add the delimiters and then the next word and so on. This could be done with a loop, but could someone help me figure out how to break the input string into words and then move the delimiters? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What defines the delimiter? Is it known prior to calling the method or is it somewhere in the input string?

Comment: The words can be seprated by any non-letter character. So anything such as numbers or symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.split(String)`, which returns an array of `String` with the delimiter removed.  The param passed in is a regex expression that is use to identify the delimiters.  It is not returned in the array results.

```
 "no0b".split("0")
```

would return an array of `["no","b"]`

Comment: No, `String.split()` takes separators, not delimiters.  Believe me, I know: I wrote the documentation for the function that the Java junkies originally pinched it from.  They messed up a few other things, too, BTW. It returns a list of length one on an zero-length string. That’s just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[Visit java doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) site whenever you have simple questions like this. There are a lot of good information you can find in the java docs. Search up String object in the documents and you will find all the methods you can call from a string object. The `String.split([a-zA-Z])` will split up the strings by if its a letter or non letter.